# Increment my server-port in my Config file

Tags: linux, bash, scripting

I want to make a Bash Script, that will increment my server-port option in my Config file every time with +1 if i run my script. My config file looks like this.

```
server-port=1000
server-online=true
level-name=Hapos
type=XZC
```

So as a example how it needs to work

```
# ./script.sh
we will now change the port
# cat config.txt
1001
-----------------
# ./script.sh
we will now change the port
# cat config.txt
1002
-----------------
# ./script.sh
we will now change the port
# cat config.txt
1003
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Incrementing with awk

Let's start with this config file:

```
$ cat config.txt 
server-port=1000
server-online=true
level-name=Hapos
type=XZC
```

We can increment the port using awk:

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS== '$1 == "server-port"{$2++} 1' config.txt 
server-port=1001
server-online=true
level-name=Hapos
type=XZC
```

The code works as follows:

- `-F=` sets the field separator on input to `=`.
- `-v OFS==` sets the field separator on output to `=`.
- `$1 == "server-port"{$2++}` tests to see if the first field is `server-port`.  If it is, it increments the second field.
- `1` is awk's cryptic shorthand for print-the-line.

#### Changing in-place using a modern (>=4.1.0) GNU awk

```
$ awk -i inplace -F= -v OFS== '$1 == "server-port"{$2++} 1' config.txt 
$ cat config.txt 
server-port=1001
server-online=true
level-name=Hapos
type=XZC
$ awk -i inplace -F= -v OFS== '$1 == "server-port"{$2++} 1' config.txt 
$ cat config.txt 
server-port=1002
server-online=true
level-name=Hapos
type=XZC
```

#### Changing in-place with other awks

```
$ awk -F= -v OFS== '$1 == "server-port"{$2++} 1' config.txt >tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ config.txt
$ cat config.txt 
server-port=1003
server-online=true
level-name=Hapos
type=XZC
```

#### Alternative input file

Suppose our file has a dash where the above one had an equal sign:

```
$ cat config.txt
server-port-1000
server-online=true
level-name-Hapos
type=XZC
```

With GNU awk, we can increment the port number with:

```
awk -i inplace -F- -v OFS=- '/^server-port-/{$NF++} 1' config.txt
```

This produces the new file:

```
$ cat config.txt
server-port-1001
server-online=true
level-name-Hapos
type=XZC
```

With an awk other than an up-to-date GNU awk:

```
$ awk -F- -v OFS=- '/^server-port-/{$NF++} 1' config.txt >tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ config.txt
$ cat config.txt
server-port-1002
server-online=true
level-name-Hapos
type=XZC
```

#### Notes on security and temporary files for non-GNU solution

The updating in-place with the non-GNU awk requires creating a temporary file.  It is common to put temporary files in `/tmp` but this is a security risk: other users can write to this directory making race conditions possible.  This danger can be minimized by using a utility such as `mktemp` that makes hard-to-guess file names.  A still better solution is to put the tmp file in a directory to which only the user has write-access.  This can be the home directory.

In the above, the tmp file is put in the same directory as the config.txt file.  It is likely that this directory is secure because, it is where the config.txt is.  If it isn't, steps should be taken.

For more information on this issue, see [Greg's FAQ 062](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/062).

Comment: Thanks! for helping me out. It is working super! i really appreciate it!

Comment: Hmm, how do i make it still work if i change in my Config, server-port=100 to server-port-100. Because if it do that it is not working anymore.

Comment: @PxlPenguin Just to clarify, because comment formatting is poor, is that `server-port-` (which includes a trailing dash), followed by a blank space, followed by the number?  I can make that work but I just want to be sure what we are working with.

Comment: No, it isn't followed by a space it is just server-port-(Here the port Number)
I hope you can get this working ;)

Comment: @PxlPenguin No problem.  See updated answer for incrementing the file with the new format.

Comment: Boo, hiss re: `tmp$$` rather than using `mktemp` to create temporary files -- with PID values being predictable, this leaves the tool open to symlink attacks by any other user able to write to the directory.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Not so fast: `mktemp` is important if the tmp file is going in a world-writable directory, such as `/tmp` or `/var/tmp`.  The OP here is working on config files so they are not going to be in such a directory.  See [Greg's FAQ 062](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/062) for a discussion of this.

Comment: That's why I qualified "any other user able to write to the directory", as opposed to "any user on the system", as would be the case for /tmp.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy How about if I update the answer to put the tmp files in `~/`?

Comment: That would make the `mv` non-atomic if `$HOME` is on a different filesystem. Actually probably better as it already is, with perhaps a note of caution suggesting switching to mktemp _if_ the current directory is writable by any other user.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy OK.  Answer updated with security info.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86651/discussion-between-charles-duffy-and-john1024).

Comment: Thanks, for the Security information! But i have another Question, If i have the Bash Script to change the Port in another location then the Config self, it can't change the Config. How can i have the Bash Script in another directory then the Config self. But still be able to change the Port?

Comment: @PxlPenguin Yes.  Just change every occurrence of `config.txt` to `/path/to/config.txt` using whatever the correct path is.  (If you use the non-GNU version, then _also_ put a path in front of the tmp file name.)

Comment: And, is there a possibility to run the awk -F- -v OFS=- '/server-port-/{$NF++} 1' config.txt >tmp$$ && mv tmp$$ config.txt In the same Script? Because if i do that Currently it is overwritting the awk command too, and it doesn't work.

Comment: @PxlPenguin OK.  If I correctly understand what you asking, then the commands in the updated answer should work.  The update adds a `^` so that `/server-port-/` is replaced with `/^server-port-/`.  This means that the command will only act on lines that start with `server-port-` and ignore other lines that merely contain  `server-port-` somewhere in the line.

Comment: Hmm, i mean to make it more understandable. I have the line screen -S Test-1 -p -X stuff "sh test.sh" In my Script and i want to add a awk in that Script to, to change everytime i use the Script it will change the 1 to a 2 etc..

Comment: @PxlPenguin What is in `test.sh`?

Comment: @John1024 It, is to run a certain Server of me!

Comment: @PxlPenguin That leaves me with more questions than answers.  How is the awk command being run?  Are you saying that it is in the same file as the port number assignment?

Comment: The awk Command, and the server-port=1000 -x -f -p are on the same file the -x -f -p is new btw. But if i have the awk Command and the server-port.... in the same file, and if i run now the script to change the port of it, it is removing the -x -f -p after the port number!